# Class which removes objects from array in main

Tags: java, arrays, oop, object

I'm working on an object-oriented program in Java that allows you to keep track of a horde of zombies. A zombie can be identified either by a unique id number or a single name, and we want to note how many limbs each zombie currently possesses. Zombies may leave the horde either by their own accord or removed by a zombie hunter.

Currently I'm trying to work on the zombie hunter class, I need it to remove objects from an array of zombies in main after it meets a certain condition, and the other classes should be done I believe:

**zombieHorde.java**

```
public class ZombieHorde{
  int hordeSize = 0;

  public ZombieHorde(int hordeSize){
    Zombie zombies = new Zombie[hordeSize];
    hordeSize++;
  }
}
```

**zombie.java**

```
import horde;

public class Zombie {
  int hordeSize = 0;

  public Zombie(String name, int limbs) {
    this.name = name;
    this.limbs = limbs;
  }

  public int loseLimbs() {
    limbs--;
  }

  public int getLimbs() {
    return limbs;
  }

  public void leaveHorde() {
    hordeSize--;
  }
}
```

**main.java**

```
// accuracy to determine if a zombie hunter kills its mark,
// then if it does I can decrease the horde size and get rid
// of the object/kill the zombie, use random for determining
// # of limbs, and if zombies join a horde, etc.
// main class creates a horde, creates zombies and adds them
// to a horde, and the zombie hunter object

// could also have multiple Hordes, ZombieHunters!

import Zombie;
import ZombieHorde;
import ZombieHunter;

public class MyZombieGame{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    // creates horde
    ZombieHorde h = ZombieHorde(hordeSize);

    // create zombies and add them to array
    Zombie myZombie = Zombie(Chuck, 4);

    // create zombie hunter to remove from array?
    
  }
}
```

And **zombiehunter.java**

```
import horde;

public class ZombieHunter{
  public void shootAt(name){

  }
}
```

What I'm thinking is I could have an accuracy assigned to a zombie hunter, and then compare that to a random number, and if the accuracy is higher, then the zombie hunter hits its mark and kills a zombie, then I remove a zombie object from the ZombieHorde array in main! If that makes sense, although I'm a little tripped up by them leaving on their own accords, any ideas would be awesome about an approach to this and how I should go about removing the objects from the array.

I'm brand new to Java so there might be some errors I apologize if this is the case! Just looking for a push in the right direction!

Comment: hordeSize++; this makes no sense, since you just update the local variable which isn't used anymore later on. ZombieHorde h = ZombieHorde(hordeSize);

    // create zombies and add them to array
    Zombie myZombie = Zombie(Chuck, 4); => this simply won't compile. First, learn the basics

Comment: how is main supposed to reach that variable? Start by writing a main that will compile.

Comment: Sounds like you have some fun ideas!  Implement and test them one at a time, build your program up slowly and make sure each new thing works properly before adding the next.  Helps prevent errors :)  Write test code!

In Java, arrays are declared as Zombie[] zombies rather than your current approach in ZombieHorde.java.  Both work, but working with convention is best.

The hordeSize variable confuses me.  I see no reason for it to exist at all in the Zombie class, the class should not know or care how many other zombies yet lurk.  In ZombieHorde, it will equal 0 with your current code.

Comment: ZombieHoard should keep track of the number of Zombies. Not Zombie or main.

Comment: Are you supposed to use arrays ? If not you could use [`ArrayList`](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_arraylist.asp). You could forget about size. If you come from C or another low level language, you should follow some tutorials, Java is very different from those language don't think applying the same logic is good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to concider using some sort of map (i.e. a Hashmap) instead of an array.

```
public class ZombieHorde{
  
  //note that class attributes are usually private
  private int hordeSize = 0; //actually no need for hordSize here, you could just use .size();
  private HashMap<String, Zombie> zombieHorde;

  public ZombieHorde(){
    //instanciate Hashmap
    this.zombieHorde = new HashMap<String, Zombie>();    
  }

  public void addToHorde(Zombie zombie){
     //assuming there is a get name method implemented
     this.zombieHorde.put(zombie.getName, zombie);
     this.hordeSize++;
  }

  public void removeFromHorde(Zombie zombie){
     //assuming there is a get name method implemented
     this.zombieHorde.remove(zombie.getName);
     this.hordeSize--;
  }

}
```

On a map you can use functions like add and remoive which makes it useful for usecases like this. If you wanna know the hordeSize you can also just use `zombieHodre.size()`
(Not sure if my code is 100% correct but you should get the idea).

Comment: This helps a ton and makes a lot of sense to me, thank you so much!